# unity LogPlayerBuildError

Tags: logging, unity-game-engine

I have a problem with unity custom log.

I just wrapped `Debug.Log` like this

```
public static MyLog(string msg)
{
   Debug.Log(msg);
}
```

When I double-click console message, it brings me this class's `Debug.Log(msg)` statement rather than the actual code where Log.Format was called.
So I searched and found TLog class in [this link](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/238229/debugconsole-console-clicking.html)

It works fine except it shows only Error type for console window.

Is there any other method which gives "Log" or "Warning" type?

Answer (score 0):

You could use print i guess, but I strongly recommend you don't do this at all.
Replacing Debug.Log with Myclass.MyLog has **no benefit but a downside**:
if someone sees this they might think you are doing something extra than just logging to the console and confuse them. Debug.log speeks for itself and unless you want to extend logging functionality by adding some extra actions I suggest you stick to Debug.Log/LogWarning/LogError etc.